# How can XSS be avoided in HTML downloads?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, xss

We have an internal web application that acts as a repository to which users can upload files.  These files can be any format, including HTML pages.

We have tested than in IE8, if you download an HTML file that contains some script that tries to access your cookies and, after downloading, you choose the "Open" option, the script executes and gets your cookie information with no problems at all.

Actually, that script could use XmlHttpRequest object to call the server and do some malicious operations within the session of the user who downloaded the file.

Is there any way to avoid this?  We have tested that both Chrome and Firefox do not let this happen.  How could this behaviour be avoided in any browser, including IE8?

Comment: What does "Open" actually do? Show the page in the browser? If so, what is the URL of the page when that happens?

Comment: @bzlm: It's like with any attachment; if you force the browser to prompt for the download window (wich content-disposition), you can still click open, and it opens using the url used to load it, which is obviously on the same domain as his cookies, hence my suggestion of running (the downloads) on an alternative domain.

Comment: @bzlm is on the right track: If you open a HTML file locally, it won't be able to access cookies, nor issue Ajax requests, to a remote server due to the single domain policy. Only if it's opened directly on the server that is possible.

Comment: @Noon That's a good suggestion. But "it opens using the url used to load it" - I would rather have expected a `file://` URL, or at least the document to open in "local file system" mode (see @Pekka 's comment). Are you sure that is what happens?

Comment: @bzlm: Come to think of it, I'm not sure. I'd have to test it ...

Comment: @bzlm: When opening the file in IE8, it shows the URL from which it was downloaded.  If it's been downloaded with Chrome or Firefox, it shows file:// URL.  That's why only IE8 allows that document to access cookies.

Comment: @antur123 That's interesting. I would not have expected that. Go with Noon's alternate-domain suggestion. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922872/how-can-xss-be-avoided-in-html-downloads/3922894#3922894

Comment: @antur you may be able to block this behaviour by sending the right headers (Search for "IE force download" on SO) but I'm not sure whether this is 100% reliable (which in this case, it would have to be.)

Comment: @Pekka Without "IE force download", surely there would not even be an  "Open" option available to the user?

Comment: @bzlm true. But I still can't believe that "Open" opens stuff in the server context. That would be horrible.

Comment: @Pekka Horrible... IE... sounds about right. It's probably depending on what Zone the original URL is in, and what your security settings are. But the defaults seem to be horrible. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't allow the upload of arbritary content. It's exclusively a terrible idea.

One potential "solution" could be to only host the untrusted uploads on a domain that doesn't have any cookies and that the user doesn't associate any trust with in any way. This would be a "solution", but certainly not the ideal one.

Some more practical options could be an authorisation-based process, where each file goes through an automated review and then a manual confirmation of the automated cleaning/analysis phase.

All in all though, it's a very bad idea to allow the general public to do this.

Comment: +1 for storing the uploads on a different domain and the general notion that this is always dangerous

Comment: We will consider the option of downloading files from a different domain, and will keep an eye on the system to see if we are eventually forced to reject any dangerous upload.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: [GitHub releases](https://github.com/cirosantilli/test/releases/tag/3.0) allow any extension and seem to use the domain solution through S3. Dropbox also allows arbitrary filetypes.

Answer (score 5):

That's a really bad idea from a security point of view. Still, if you wish to do this, include HTTP response header `Content-disposition: attachment` It will force browser to download file instead of opening it. In Apache, it's done by adding `Header set Content-disposition "attachment"` to .htaccess file.

Note that it's a bad idea just to add `Content-type: text/plain` as mentioned in one of the answers, because it won't work for Internet Explorer. When IE receives file with text/plain content-type header, it turns on its MIME sniffer which tries to define file's real content-type (because some servers send all the files with text/plain). In case it meets HTML code inside a file, it will force the browser to serve file as text/html and render it.

Comment: [This blog post](http://i8jesus.com/?p=64) says that just `Content-Disposition` is not enough, but I don't know enough to say how reliable it is and if still applies.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to have the users upload HTML files, you should make sure the HTML files in this directory are served with the mime type text/plain rather than text/html or similar.

This will prevent the opened files from executing scripts in the browser. If you're using apache, see the [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) directive.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and may do the trick. I'd still be concerned about serving the content from the same domain, but I think this should probably be done regardless.

Comment: Beware of content sniffing. Because Apache ships with `text/plain` by default for unknown files, browsers are forced to treat `text/plain` as invitation to guess the actual type.